# Ruby 1.9.2 + Sinatra - Requiring authentication on certain routes

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, aop

Before I begin, this is basically a port of an existing ASP.MVC REST style service to Sinatra. I am fairly new to Ruby so dont really know the best practises yet, and the web seems a bit torn on the subject.

So currently in the ASP flavour we have some controllers like so:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Authenticate]
    public ActionResult AccessSecretStuffs()
    {...}

    public ActionResult AccessPublicStuffs()
    {...}
}
```

Now we use a filter to make sure that any actions with Authenticate check for authentication from the current user before loading the action. The routes setup for these are fairly vanilla, they just map to the controller and actions.

Now in Ruby land using Sinatra you dont tend to have controllers, everything is an action, and as we are purely looking to expose data in a restful way this seems great. However I need to be able to make sure that whenever certain routes are called with Sinatra that it will basically call a bit of code first to check if they can access the action, then if not redirect them to the login page.

I was thinking of just putting in some AOP to cover this, but after a bit of reading everyone says Ruby doesnt need AOP and already provides most of the functionality out of the box. So can anyone shed some light on the best practise for doing this?

Sinatra documentation has a before method that would be applicable, but then I would need to do a before method for every other route method, which isnt ideal. In my mind I just want to declare a route, and then put some sort of annotation/attribute at the end which indicates that something needs to happen...

Hope that makes some sort of sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have annotations as such, but Sinatra does provide custom filtering mechanisms.

When defining a route, you can put additional conditions, such as various header values and whatnot. You can also define custom conditions:

```
set(:auth) do |*roles|   # <- notice the splat here
    condition do
        unless logged_in? && roles.any? {|role| current_user.in_role? role }
            redirect "/login/", 303 
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can define a route like this:

```
get "/secret", :auth => [:user, :admin] do
    ...
end
```

or if you don't need to pass any arguments, before block can take a path as an argument:

```
before '/secret/*' do
    authenticate!
end
```

You can read more at [Sinatra readme page](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html)

Comment: I cant believe I never saw that bit in the readme before, feel like a bit of an idiot... I just gave it a try but if I want to have a custom filter that takes no arguments how would that look? i.e get "/secret", :auth do ... end

Comment: It's not that simple. Technically second argument to `get` is map of conditions, so you need to do something line `:auth => nil`

Comment: you could actually use this approach with `get "/secret", protected: true do`